# Neo4j Cypher: Display Properties of Relationships/Edges in Neo4j Explorer Web App (yFiles)

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I want to use the [neo4j explorer web app](https://yworks.com/neo4j-explorer) (based on the yFiles programming library) for visualisation of my database.

Is there a way in the app to write the properties of a relationship on the screen instead of something like `ACTED_IN`?

Or is it possible to express it via cypher, so that I can paste it in the app?

Many thanks!

Comment: No, I don't have an active subscription at yWorks. My question is only for personal purposes. Maybe you can help me with the cypher code. For example let's take the Neo4j Movie Database. Now I want to change the "ACTED_IN" with its own edge properties "what role the actor played".

Comment: By "in yFiles" - are you actually referring to the [neo4j explorer web app](https://yworks.com/neo4j-explorer)? Or is this about a [yFiles for HTML](https://yworks.com/yfileshtml) - powered program you are authoring in JavaScript? Or Java?

Comment: yes, it is the neo4j explorer web app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is currently not possible with the Neo4j Explorer app. As a workaround, you could export the graph as a .graphml file and load it into [yEd Live](https://www.yworks.com/yed-live/). yEd Live is a diagram editor that supports diagrams generated with Neo4j Explorer and lets you add edge labels manually.

Please also note that you can view the properties of a relationship in the bottom-left box by click-selecting it.

Comment: Hi Jens, thank you for your feedback! I know that I can view all properties by clicking on the relationship. But that is not the way I want to present the data in the graph. I want to produce 2D drawings with automated visualized properties. Maybe you know a way to change the edge type with the edge properties in cypher code.